# C: Sorting order from file input, receiving an abundance of compilation error

Tags: c, file, sorting, compilation, stdin

This is my first time working with file input and pointers so I'm sorry if my code seems like a mess. I was looking at other Stack Overflow solutions as a reference. My code is meant to find the longest word in a file where I can assume that the input text will not have a word longer than 1000 characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// main() must return an integer
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE *file; //open an existing file
    file = fopen(argv[1], "r"); //using argv as a pointer to an array of pointers to arrays of characters
    char *sentence = (char *) malloc(100 * sizeof(char)); //memory allocation, unsure what to use for size*


    //fgets - reads a line from the specified stream and stores it into the string pointed to
    //max amount set to 1000
    while (fgets(sentence, 1000, file) != NULL) {
        char *word;
        int maxlen = 0;
        char *maxW;
        //max size of 1000 characters
        maxW = (char *) calloc(1000, sizeof(char));
        word = (char *) calloc(1000, sizeof(char));
        word = strtok(sentence, " ");  //using strtok to break sentance to token

        //checking size of word with maxlen
        while (word != NULL) {
            if (strlen(word) > maxlen) {
                maxlen = strlen(word);
                strcpy(maxW, word);
            }
            word = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        printf("%s\n", maxW); //printing the max sized word
        maxlen = 0; //reset

        return 0;
    }
}
```

I've only been using command line in windows to compile my code using gcc and I tried to use CLion but I can't figure out how to use CLion at the moment.

Edit: oops removed the image.

Comment: Should the malloc call for sentence be multiplied by 1000 instead of 100?

Comment: Dont'post images of text but post the text.

Comment: The code aside (multiple things in there will eventually need fixing) your build system (or build command, which you didn't share with us) is broken. [Your code compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2d337b637a7adf1) (which by no means indicates it is "correct").

Comment: @JonnyHenly oh, I see it now, you can delete this comment now, I deleted mine.

Comment: It compiles and links here too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few observations:

- max size of sentence is smaller than max size of a word. Better use constants or macros to avoid typos like this.
- You're using `argv[1]` (command line parameters) but nothing guarantees that the user will send a filename as parameter. Better validate this with a appropriate message (argc is the parameter count).
- `fopen` tries to open the file, if it cannot do it, returns NULL, your code must do the  verification.
- The code allocates sentence, word and maxW for each line, but that's incorrect, so move these allocations to the top of main code.
- `word` is just a pointer over `sentence`, so it doesn't need have memory allocated at all.
- Your program only reads the first line and then stops, that's because it has a `return 0;` inside `while`.
- Always `free` the memory that you allocates with `malloc`/`calloc`.

Apart from those observations, your code is almost there.

Reorganizing your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Using constants avoid typos
#define MAX_SIZE    1000

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Tokens not considered as part of a word
    const char tokens[] = " \t\n\r,/:[]=().<>";
    int maxlen = 0;
    // calloc(a,b) == malloc(a*b)
    char *sentence = (char *) malloc(MAX_SIZE * sizeof(char)); 
    char *maxW     = (char *) calloc(MAX_SIZE, sizeof(char));
    char *word;
    // try open and validate
    FILE *file     = fopen(argv[1], "rt"); 
    if(file == NULL){
        printf("file '%s' cannot be opened!\n", argv[1]);
        return 1; // !=0 means error to OS
    }

    while (fgets(sentence, MAX_SIZE, file) != NULL) {
        word = strtok(sentence, tokens);  
        while (word != NULL) {
            if (strlen(word) > maxlen) {
                maxlen = strlen(word);
                strcpy(maxW, word);
            }
            word = strtok(NULL, tokens);
        }
    }
    printf("Max word='%s' (len=%d)\n", maxW, maxlen); 

    // Don't forget free memory allocated with malloc/calloc
    free(sentence);
    free(maxW);

    return 0;
 }
```

And executing over the same program file:

```
$ gcc program.c
$ ./program program.c
Max word='considered' (len=10)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your input! I ended doing a bit more research and am using fseek over fgets now and have my code working as intended! Thank you for pointing out constants + free memory allocation, completely overlooked that!

Comment: I think my post answered your original question, could you please accept it?

Comment: Will do! Sorry first time using stackoverflow!